# Export data from orient db 1.6 and import into 1.7

Tags: import, export, orientdb

I like to know the command to export data from orient db 1.6 and import into  1.7 . The export from 1.6 admin UI and import using command line into 1.7 doesn't seem to work . I like to know the proper sequence . Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With OrientDB 1.6:

(1) Open the console with 1.6:

> cd $ORIENTDB_HOME/bin
> ./console.sh

(2) Connect to database and export it:

> orientdb> connect plocal:/mydirectory/mydb admin admin
>
> orientdb> export database /temp/mydb
>
> orientdb> exit

(3) Now open the console with 1.7 and:

> orientdb> create database plocal:/mydirectory/mydb2 admin admin plocal
>
> orientdb> import database /temp/mydb

By the way once 1.7-rc2 will be ready it will allow to "old" database to get used without export/import.

Comment: When I do that I get an exception in console :
`java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.tool.ODatabaseImport$AbstractCollectionConverter.convertSingleValue(ODatabaseImport.java:1219)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.tool.ODatabaseImport$MapConverter.convert(ODatabaseImport.java:1344)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.tool.ODatabaseImport$MapConverter.convert(ODatabaseImport.java:1321)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.tool.ODatabaseImport$LinksRewriter.visitField(ODatabaseImport.java:1180)`

Comment: Could you try with latest SNAPSHOT?

Comment: Same issue with Snapshot version too.

Comment: Put 1.7-rc2, it will load old database.